# Chrome DevTools script blackboxing not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, debugging

I am trying to use the new feature of chrome devtools "blackboxing a script". 
[This Chrome Devtools article lists script blackboxing functionality](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/blackboxing#what-happens)

#### What happens when you blackbox a script?

- Exceptions thrown from library code will not pause (if Pause on
  exceptions is enabled)
- Stepping into/out/over bypasses the library code
- Event listener breakpoints don't break in library code
- The debugger will not pause on any breakpoints set in library code.

The end result is you are debugging your application code instead of third party resources.

I have tried to blackbox the file directly by right clicking the file from source tab and everything goes right the yellow notification shows at the top of file "This script is blackboxed in debugger". Strangely none of the above listed points work, debugger goes through blackboxed script also event listeners reference the blackboxed script. I have also enabled Developer Tools experiments at chrome://flags/
With these options set i thought i would have been ok, i also have the latest chrome at this time 39.0 beta,i have no idea what i'm missing. **Did anybody go through this?**
 **Thnx!**

[image]
[image]

Comment: It has worked for me few times. But I noticed the same behavior on a script today. Weird

Comment: Having the same problem. Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: I'm pretty sure something broke recently in Chrome

Comment: @AntonioBrandao i could'nt find anything helpful, i lost interest and i just stopped using it

Comment: Just tested it again and can confirm that it is still not working as expected on chrome 52 on Windows 7. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/breakpoints/step-code#blackbox-third-party-code) has also moved.

Comment: There is an issue filed in chromium for this: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=589980&q=blackbox&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. One quick and easy way is to look at your Call Stack. As a for instance, Right-Click on one of the 'jquery' functions and select 'black box' from the menu. Nothing else needed. In this example jquery.js will be step-over from that point on.

Answer (score 1):

In your screenshot, I can see a breakpoint.

If you put a breakpoint, it will always break (except if you deactivate it, of course), even with blackboxing being active.

Comment: blackboxing works in my chrome, windows, 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit), colleague has the same machine and chrome version as me, but his blackboxing does not work, strange. it's such a useful feature.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and used good old

> have you tried turning it off and on again?

Go to developer tools settings -> Blackboxing -> Remove all entries one by one + disable `Blackbox content scripts`

Blackboxed again and after that this works fine.